Two if statements in a list comprehension
Looking at another question, I saw what I assumed was a simple typo or misunderstanding of list comprehension syntax -- but it actually worked!
This is a simplified version of the code in that question:
message = "ABCABCABCABC"
data = [ch for ch in message if ch != 'A' if ch != 'B']
print(data)

It prints ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C'].
The double if conditions at the end seem very odd to me.  Why isn't that a syntax error?  How is it parsed?

Maybe python list comprehension with multiple 'if's can help you. My straightforward idea is to use ast to see how the code is parsed.

This is documented here(https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.comprehension)

Move the ch at the beginning to the end as lst.append(ch), and place a : after every for and if part. That’s basically what every list comprehension expands to.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries is probably a better reference, though it could probably do a better job of describing the semantics of multiple if clauses. (As far as I can tell, if cond1 if cond2 is semantically equivalent to if cond1 and cond2. I wouldn't think this would be a common way to write a filter outside of machine-generated code.)

It's odd in this case, but I prefer it over if+and when the two conditions are longer and I put them on separate lines.

oh wow never realized this would work

You could just write if ch not in "AB" or if ch not in ("A", "B")

@OysterShucker yes I know I could have written it that way.  My question was about this specific syntax.  I didn't know it existed.

I know. I put my comment here for new people, in an attempt to make them reconsider chaining if statements at the end of their comprehension. It may be possible, but it is not likely to ever be the best way to create a filter. It's probably going to generally be the worst way.
